# Array instead of JQuery object

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I have a backbone application with a couple of callbacks. And at some when I initialize view I cache jQuery object in a variable:

```
this.block = $('#block');
```

But when I try to log this object from some callback in console instead of usual

```
[<div id="block"></div>]
```

I get this array:

```
[context: document, selector: "#block", jquery: "1.10.2", constructor: function, init: function…]
```

How can I get usual jQuery object from this array?

Comment: That _is_ a usual jQuery object.

Comment: yup, that was a pretty screwup

Comment: dude, i dont get it ... you need dom reference when you log your jquery object? well, then just do this $myJQueryObject.get(0) or $myJQueryObject[0]

Comment: _"when I try common methods like animate on this object it doesn't work"_ - Please show the JS code that tries to use the object.

Comment: http://pastie.org/8207891 commented lines are the ones that don't work, the lies below the commented lines are working replacement. I'm sorry, it's a coffeescript can't paste javascript.

Answer (score 0):

That is the usual jQuery object, it just has some additional properties  because Backbone extends some prototypes.

Comment: I believe the properties shown in the question are standard jQuery properties (though perhaps not documented properties).

Comment: still, when I try common methods like animate on this object it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

If your functions such as .animate() aren't working, you may need to use $("#block").get(0);

Comment: In my view, I cache `$('#block')` to `this.block`. Then in function when I use either `this.block.animate(...)` or `this.block.get(0).animate(...)` or `this.block[0].animate(...)` it's still doesn't work. `this` refers to view object.

Comment: Could you try it without the variable?

Comment: it works without the variable, but the matter is I want to cache it

Comment: Hmm, the problem may be caused because you are saving it in the this variable, which gets overwritten with every event. Try saving it in a custom variable.

Comment: `.get(0)` will return the actual DOM element referenced within the jQuery object, and you can't call `.animate()` or other jQuery methods directly on a DOM element.

Comment: Please let us know if you got it to work or need further help, Prostakov